# NUL character and ANSI-C quoting

Tags: bash

I'm attempting to send a binary string to a program using ANSI-C quoted strings. This works fine:

```bsh
echo $'\x23\x51\x66\x39\x01\x5f\x2f' | cat -v
# output: #Qf9^A_/
```

However, if I have a NUL character (ASCII code 0) in the data, it terminates the string:

```bsh
echo $'\x23\x00\x66\x39\x01\x5f\x2f' | cat -v
# output: #
```

I'm aware that strings in the C language are null-terminated so I'm guessing a similar constraint applies to this quoting method.

Is there a way I can send ASCII 0 to my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `printf` instead of `echo`.

```
$ printf "\x23\x00\x66\x39\x01\x5f\x2f" | od -c
0000000   #  \0   f   9 001   _   /
```

Comment: Success! Thanks for the tip.